# Join multiple async generators in Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I would like to listen for events from multiple instances of the same object and then merge this event streams to one stream. For example, if I use async generators:

```
class PeriodicYielder: 
    def __init__(self, period: int) -> None: 
        self.period = period 

    async def updates(self): 
        while True: 
            await asyncio.sleep(self.period)
            yield self.period
```

I can successfully listen for events from one instance:

```
async def get_updates_from_one(): 
    each_1 = PeriodicYielder(1) 
    async for n in each_1.updates(): 
        print(n)
# 1
# 1
# 1
# ...
```

But how can I get events from multiple async generators? In other words: how can I iterate through multiple async generators in the order they are ready to produce next value?

```
async def get_updates_from_multiple(): 
    each_1 = PeriodicYielder(1) 
    each_2 = PeriodicYielder(2) 
    async for n in magic_async_join_function(each_1.updates(), each_2.updates()): 
        print(n)
# 1
# 1
# 2
# 1
# 1
# 2
# ...
```

Is there such **magic_async_join_function** in stdlib or in 3rd party module?

Comment: Is [`gather()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) what you are looking for?

Comment: @SuperShoot `gather()` returns list with size _n_ as result of gathering _n_ coroutines. I would like to merge _n_ multiple async generators to be one async generator. Something like `itertools.chain()` but for async iterables and not exhausting first iterable to check if second iterable is ready to yield.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use wonderful [aiostream](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. It'll look like this:

```
import asyncio
from aiostream import stream


async def test1():
    for _ in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        yield 1


async def test2():
    for _ in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        yield 2


async def main():
    combine = stream.merge(test1(), test2())

    async with combine.stream() as streamer:
        async for item in streamer:
            print(item)


asyncio.run(main())
```

**Result:**

```
1
1
2
1
1
2
1
2
2
2
```

Comment: Wow, looks good! Will check it out!

Comment: Mikhail Gerasimov, thank you!

Comment: @AndreySemakin you're welcome! :)

Answer (score 18):

If you wanted to avoid the dependency on an external library (or as a learning exercise), you could merge the async iterators using a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html):

```
def merge_async_iters(*aiters):
    # merge async iterators, proof of concept
    queue = asyncio.Queue(1)
    async def drain(aiter):
        async for item in aiter:
            await queue.put(item)
    async def merged():
        while not all(task.done() for task in tasks):
            yield await queue.get()
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(drain(aiter)) for aiter in aiters]
    return merged()
```

This passes the test from [Mikhail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55300515/1600898), but it's not perfect: it doesn't propagate the exception in case one of the async iterators raises. Also, if the task that exhausts the `merged` generator returned by `merge_async_iters()` gets cancelled, or if the same generator is not exhausted to the end, the individual `drain` tasks are left hanging.

A more complete version could handle the first issue by detecting an exception and transmitting it through the queue. The second issue can be resolved by `merged` generator cancelling the `drain` tasks as soon as the iteration is abandoned. With those changes, the resulting code looks like this:

```
def merge_async_iters(*aiters):
    queue = asyncio.Queue(1)
    run_count = len(aiters)
    cancelling = False

    async def drain(aiter):
        nonlocal run_count
        try:
            async for item in aiter:
                await queue.put((False, item))
        except Exception as e:
            if not cancelling:
                await queue.put((True, e))
            else:
                raise
        finally:
            run_count -= 1

    async def merged():
        try:
            while run_count:
                raised, next_item = await queue.get()
                if raised:
                    cancel_tasks()
                    raise next_item
                yield next_item
        finally:
            cancel_tasks()

    def cancel_tasks():
        nonlocal cancelling
        cancelling = True
        for t in tasks:
            t.cancel()

    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(drain(aiter)) for aiter in aiters]
    return merged()
```

Different approaches to merging async iterators can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50903757/1600898), and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51403277/1600898), where the latter allows for adding new streams mid-stride. The complexity and subtlety of these implementations shows that, while it is useful to know how to write one, actually doing so is best left to well-tested external libraries such as [aiostream](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that cover all the edge cases.

Comment: thank you for a great explanation!